# Can I debug a core generated by a C++ binary without debug symbols using the same binary recompiled with debug symbols

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to debug a core file generated by a C++ binary without debug symbols.  In order to do effective debugging, I need the debug symbols, so I've recompiled the same code with -g option in order to generate debug symbols in the recompiled binary.  Can I now debug the same core file generated by the first binary (without debug symbols) using the second binary (has debug symbols, everything else is same) ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compiled original executable with e.g. `g++ -O2 ...`, you can not (as you probably have discovered) use a new executable built with `g++ -g ...` to debug the `core` -- GDB needs the symbols to match, and they would not (due to difference in optimization levels).

What you *can* do is build the new executable with the same optimization as the original, but *also* with debug symbols: `g++ -O2 -g ...`.

After you've built a new executable, run `nm old.a.out > old.nm`, `nm new.a.out > new.nm` and compare the outputs. They should be identical or very very close.

If they are, you should be able to debug a `core` produced by `old.a.out` using `new.a.out`.

In the future, you should always build your executable with debug symbols, then keep the full copy, but ship a copy without debug info:

```
cp a.out a.out.debug
strip --strip-debug a.out
# a.out is now good to send to customers
# keep a.out.debug for future debugging
```